# Property of a function $f$ satisfying $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq (x - y)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am given a relation about differentiable function that $$|f(x)-f(y)| \le (x-y)^2$$ and if $f(0)=0$ then possible value of $f(1)=?$
I saw the slope form and rewrote it as $$ \frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{x-y} \le (x-y)$$ which then becomes $$\frac{dy}{dx} \le x-y $$ how to solve this inequality ? I don't think I can directly solve this diffential equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say, "which then becomes", presumably you're taking the limit as $x \to y$. Taking the limit (and treating the absolute value carefully) gives
$$\left\vert \frac{df}{dx}\right\vert \leq 0,$$
and in particular equality holds. So, if $f$ is defined on all of $[0, 1]$, it constant on that interval, and so
$$f(1) = f(0) = 0.$$

I suppose that if $f$ is not defined at some point between $0$ and $1$, then $f(1)$ could be any value.

Comment: Oh thanks I didn't get the question quite well.

Comment: You're welcome. You got the key algebraic manipulation and the idea of applying the appropriate limit, the rest is more or less applying definitions.

Answer (score 1):

$$|f(x)-f(y)|\leq (x-y)^2\Rightarrow -(x-y)^2\leq (f(x)-f(y))\leq (x-y)^2$$
Substitute $y=0$ to get
$$-x^2\leq f(x)\leq x^2$$
at $x=1$ you have the range for possible values of $f(1)$ as
$$-1\leq f(1)\leq 1$$